# EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, exception, plpgsql

I have an exception in Oracle PL/SQL that needs to be ported to PostgreSQL pl/pgsql. Below is the oracle variant

```
EXCEPTION 
WHEN OTHERS THEN 
NULL;
```

What is the PL/PGSQL variant?

Comment: (1) Please provide more details about the code (perhaps simplified).  (2) The general topic of exception handling in Postgres or Oracle is probably too broad for a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 4):

It's the same syntax. Compare the 2 following executions:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
RAISE division_by_zero;
EXCEPTION 
WHEN OTHERS THEN 
NULL; 
END;
$$

DO
```

And:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
RAISE division_by_zero;
END;
$$

ERROR:  division_by_zero
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 3 at RAISE
```

Answer (score 1):

First, avoid trapping "any exception"s like that with no specific behavior at all. Except for very simple functions, consider logging it somewhere, or rewrite the code in a more elegant manner.

I found it [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/plpgsql-control-structures.html): apparently, you don't need to put anything at all.

You should try the following:

```
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
  -- Do nothing
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

***DO NOT*** port this as it is. It is a **BUG ALWAYS**. If you do nothing else at least log the error. If where it occurs is interactive, or data loading, or report generating, or a whole host of others then create some kind of message indicating the process failed. If users are depending on this data and it is not there it is your application that is broken, not the users expectations. I understand your are migrating a system but while doing so you should not carry forward obvious bugs. This is one.

Comment: that's a blatantly overreaching statement. there are quite a few reasons to use "WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL"; for instance, PostgreSQL, doesn't have CREATE OR REPLACE for triggers, AND there is no need to recreate triggers when functions of the same name are replaced. using an OTHERS WHEN exception is a clean way to CREATE OR IGNORE if a trigger already exists, since there is absolutely no reason to create it again